# Multiple inheritance: accessing common interface

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance

Given the following:

```
class A {
//
}

class B {
//
}

class Ad1 : public A {
//
}

class Ad2 : public A {
//
}

class Ad1B : public Ad1, public B {
//
}

class Ad2B : public Ad2, public B {
//
}
```

Types Ad1B and Ad2B share a common inherited interface (the combined interface of A and B). 
Is it possible to create a pointer to which objects of either type Ad1B or Ad2B can be assigned, and through which this shared interface can be accessed? Is there any way to achieve the same effect?

Answer (score 1):

The common interface of `Ad1B` and `Ad2B` is `A` and `B` - so you could store pointer to object of class `Ad1B` or `Ad2B` either in `A*p` or in `B*p` and access `A` or `B` functionality respectively

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, Neither a pointer to class A or B is a pointer "through which the shared interface can be accessed"

Comment: @ROX actually you are right - looks like I misunderstood the question. But the answer is there - directly you can't make it work, only using some kind of wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

You want a pointer to a base class that doesn't exist. You want some pointer to a type that have a combined interface of `A` and `B`. You must create a new type that have that interface.

You may pick three approaches : the template approach or the, the interface approach, or the adapter approach.

---

#### template

The template approach is quite easy. Your function that need that combined interface simply receive a reference to a `T` and user your object. If `T` have that combined interface, it will compile. It will even work with public data members.

---

#### interface

The interface approach will need to make changes to your classes. You may create that interface like this :

```
struct AB {
    // Add virtual member function
    // That is the combined version of A and B
};
```

Now `Ad1B` and `Ad2B` must inherit from the `AB` interface.

---

#### adapter

The adapter is a mix of the template and the interface. You must have an interface `AB` just as above, but instead of making `Ad1B` and `Ad2B` implement it, you create a templated adapter :

```
template<typename T>
struct Adapter : AB {
    T& object;

    // Override foo from AB
    void foo() override {
        object.foo();
    }
};
```

You can then use the `AB` interface in your code. Where you'd use the combined interface.